# change status if all of status 3 in mysqli

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have an SQL query to check status in table. This is my table and record:

```html
#table product#
id_pd    id_po    status
1        po001    0
2        po001    0
3        po001    0
4        po001    1
```

how to `echo "done";` if all of record have status `1` by id_po ?

```html
<?php
include 'connection.php';

$qry = $db->query("SELECT status FROM product WHERE id_po='$id_po' ");
$fet = $qry->fetch_assoc();
if($fet['status'] == 1){
echo "done";
}


?>
```

Comment: Add `AND status=0` to your query and check if the row-count is `0`.

Comment: i should add `while()` ?

Comment: `while()` is nice, you should definitely add `while()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check by min status:

```
$qry = $db->query("SELECT min(status) as min_status FROM product WHERE id_po='$id_po' group by id_po");
$fet = $qry->fetch_assoc();
if($fet['min_status'] == 1){
    echo "done";
}
```

Comment: BTW, why suggest used `min` ? please give me reference .

Answer (score 0):

try this, i have not try it, but I think it give you idea))

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$status = true;
$qry = $db->query("SELECT status FROM product WHERE id_po='$id_po' ");
while ($fet = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)) { 

    if($fet['status'] == 0){
        $status = false;
    }
}
if($status){
    echo 'done';
}
?>
```

Comment: i think like this, but i not yet try

Comment: if you don't need to use data from db, you can only add AND select=0 to your query, and if mysql return 0 rows, it means that all of your records have status = 1 (c) jeroen 2 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is if all status is 1 then status will be ok. In this situation, you may try this

```
 // get all
 $qry = $db->query("SELECT count(*) all_status FROM product WHERE id_po='$id_po'");
 $fet = $qry->fetch_assoc();

 // get active
 $qry2 = $db->query("SELECT count(*) all_status FROM product WHERE id_po='$id_po' AND status >= 1");
 $fet2 = $qry2->fetch_assoc();

 // match both record
 if($fet1['all_status'] == $fet2['all_status']){
   echo "done";
 }
```